# get dropdownlist selected value in controller MVC3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi in my MVC3 Project with RAZOR, i Have one doubt.

i have a page named CatlogPage.cshtml. in that page i have a Dropdownlist control.

```
 @(Html.Telerik().DropDownListFor(m => m.CatalogName)
     .BindTo(Model.CatalogName).HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:235px" }))
   <input type="submit" value="Next" />
```

I have a controller named Hierarchy.cs:
in that controller,

```
  public ActionResult Hierarchy()
       {

          // Need to get the selected value in DropDownList
          return View("Hierarchy");
       }
```

How to get the value(CatalogName) from dropDownList to the controller?

This is my model code.

```
public List<SelectListItem> GetCatalogNameModel()
        {
            try{
                var cat = from s in _entities.Catalogs.ToList()
                          select new SelectListItem()
                                  {
                                      Text = s.CatalogName,
                                      Value = s.CatalogName
                                  };
                return cat.ToList();}
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                CreateLogFiles.ErrorLog(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Logs/ErrorLog"), ex, "CatalogService", "GetCatlogName");
                return null;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Really need a bit more information on this, are you meaning the model from the top code is posted to the Hierarchy method, because if it is, you are missing passing in the model to Hierarchy. Not sure what the model is in the top code though

Comment: sorry, but that just seems to be a method that returns a list of selectitems. I was more meaning what the is the Model in the snippet of code from a view at the top, the one with the property of Model.CatalogName

Comment: @model DatabaseModel.CatalogModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So assuming that the first code snippet is from a strongly typed view (object DatabaseModel.CatalogModel) and that you are submitting the form to the Hierachy method, then passing in a CatalogModel and accessing the CatalogName should be what your after?

i.e.

```
public ActionResult Hierarchy(DatabaseModel.CatalogModel inputModel)
       {

          inputModel.CatalogName; //This will be the value from the drop down list
          return View("Hierarchy");
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

For DropDownList, I use an Int prop to receive the selected Id. So My answer is:
Add this property to your ViewModel:

```
public Int32 SelectedCatalogId {get;set;}
```

And bind it to the DropDownList:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedCatalogId, Model.GetCatalogNameModel())
```